# Secret achievements in Monkey Island: SE

Tags: xbox-360, achievements, the-secret-of-monkey-island-se

Does anyone know what the secret achievements in Monkey Island: SE are, and how to get them? (I love Monkey Island, and was somewhat shocked to just now look at my achievements and see that not only are there four I didn't get -- but that they're secret, so I don't know how to get them!)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All achievements are Secret Achievements in The Secret of Monkey Island: Special Edition, so here is the list of all Achievements and their descriptions. ([source](http://www.xbox360achievements.org/game/the-secret-of-monkey-island-special-edition/achievements/))

- **The Three Trials**
  Completed Part One: The Three Trials. Guybrush proved himself worthy to be a pirate.
- **The Journey**
  Complete Part Two: The Journey. Guybrush used a voodoo spell to travel to Monkey Island™
- **Under Monkey Island**
  Completed Part Three: Under Monkey Island. Guybrush traveled into the Monkey Head and got the root.
- **Guybrush Kicks Butt**
  Completed Last Part: Guybrush Kicks Butt. Guybrush stopped LeChuck from marrying Elaine Marley.
- **Sharp Tongue**
  Guybrush learned all of the insults, and is the wittiest/deadliest pirate what ever swung a sword.
- **Ten Minutes Later...**
  Guybrush can hold his breath for 10 minutes, but not any longer than that.
- **Escape Artist**
  Escaped from the monkey island cannibals hut 5 times.
- **RecordKeeper**
  Collected all of the notes and memos sent between Herman Toothrot, LeChuck and the Cannibals.
- **Human Cannonball**
  Finished the entire game in record time. We hope you were wearing a helmet!
- **Old School**
  Experienced the original, classic adventure game, as it was in the early 90s.
- **Determined**
  Completed the game without using any hints.
- **Marooned Everyone**
  Re-marooned Herman Toothrot and marooned Carla, Otis and Meathook on Monkey Island™.

Comment: How does the game even *know* when to give Old School? I mean, I played the thing at a friend’s house on his computer; surely there is no way an XBox 360 is capable of knowing that!

Comment: @KRyan: It refers to the "classic mode" feature. If you hit the Back button on the 360 it changes between the modern graphics and the original. You get the achievement the first time you use this feature.

Answer (score 3):

I think "Marooned Everyone" requires you to play through twice, once sinking the boat with the rock shooter, and once without.

Comment: You can make a save right before you push the rock, the re-use that to see both endings (thus avoiding 2 complete playthroughs).  Either way, the game isn't long.